# Jquery Token Input throws error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
highlight_termgithub.tokeninput.js:538
$.TokenList.selected_dropdown_itemgithub.tokeninput.js:557
e.extend.eachjquery.min.js:16
populate_dropdowngithub.tokeninput.js:556
$.TokenList.ajax_params.successgithub.tokeninput.js:670
f.extend._Deferred.e.resolveWithjquery.min.js:16
wjquery.min.js:18
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send.d
```

Getting the above error when ever an event is generated by typing any letter in the input box, I tried changing the Jquery versions but still didnt have any clue where the problem is.

Jquery Token Input: http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/
Jquery version: 1.4.4

Comment: You're going to have to post the code around your use of the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, the problem was the value variable was empty, now solved it bu rearranging the json input in the format given by the jquery-token-input plugin website.